# How to extend script on next column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

How should I modify the script, in a way that it would work also in another column, eg. by putting data in A:A date will be printed in B:B and also in C:C

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetName = "MySheet";
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() !== sheetName) return;
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetName = "MySheet";
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() !== sheetName) return;
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
  if( r.getColumn() != 3 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlutaWZdSMvllNxjKfVqrbVuO1ObosCz8JyvOGqUJIQ/edit?usp=sharing       ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,i am sharing the link of this spreadsheet, and the date and time of different coloumn should be autofill when the respective department put the heading Done, in cell